# Circle CI Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container

Tags: android, continuous-integration, circleci

I have a modern Android app that uses Kotlin and Android Architecture Components. I am trying to integrate with Circle CI, but finding Android specific documentation hard to figure out.

> What went wrong:
>   A problem occurred evaluating root project 'message-counter'.
>   Could not find method google() for arguments [] on repository container.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "com.google.gms:oss-licenses:0.9.2"
}
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
  }
}
```

**config.yml**

```
version: 2
```

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      # specify the version you desire here
      - image: circleci/android:api-26-alpha

```
working_directory: ~/repo

environment:
  JVM_OPTS: -Xmx3200m
  TERM: dumb

steps:
  - checkout

  # Download and cache dependencies
  - restore_cache:
      key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}

  - run: gradle androidDependencies

  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - ~/.gradle
      key: jars-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}-{{ checksum  "app/build.gradle" }}

  - run:
      name: Run Tests
      command: ./gradlew lint test
```

Any pointers for fixing this issue would be appreciated. Note that I am able to configure and build using Travis CI for the same repository.

Comment: What version of Gradle is Circle CI running? Using the google() repository shortcut is only available in Gradle 4.1 and above. If you can't update Gradle, you can change it to `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` instead.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I checked in gradlew and changed to ./gradlew androidDependencies. The issue I had looks to be resolved,

Comment: If you could add it as an answer, I can mark it as answered.

Comment: Sure, I've posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `google()` repository shortcut is only available for Gradle 4.1 and higher. Check to ensure that Circle CI is set up to use Gradle 4.1 and later, and that should resolve your issue.

Alternatively, you can directly reference the Google repository using:

```
maven { 
    url 'https://maven.google.com' 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updating

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
```

line in gradle-wrapper.properties file to the last version solved the same problem i encountered.